# Standard Capitalization on Pages

Tags: facebook-pages

I am trying to create a page for my business however the name "Lorna McEvoy" is being rejected and suggesting I use "Lorna Mcevoy" because of the rule of "Standard Capitalization".

The Capital 'E' in my surname is NOT incorrect and I find it insulting that I have to use my name incorrectly due to these rules. May I remind you of the successful business "McDonald's". They do not use a lower case 'd' is their advertising and I don't want to either.

I understand the rule of standard capitalization as it is explained in FAQ, however for surnames such as my own, this rule should be lifted!

Is there any way round this problem? Or anyone I can speak to that can change this problem?!

Comment: Please note: We're not Facebook. We don't have any influence whatsoever over their policies. All we can do is try to help you use Facebook (and other web apps) as they exist. I suggest you check out our [about] page as well as our [FAQ] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply edit the name after creation.